# How do I connect my domain to my hosting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I connect my domain to my hosting? I bought a domain on GoDaddy, how do I link it to GoogleCloudPlatform?

Comment: To clarify, after creating Google Cloud, I installed VestaCP, added my domain there, but later, because of the hosting item there (my hosting name), it is not possible to complete the configuration and install SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the google walkthorugh. It is very accurate and easy to undetstand in their documentation. Check it out in this link - https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/dev-portal-setup-custom-domain

Comment: How do I reinstall the operating system on GoogleCloudPlatform hosting?

Comment: @НикитаСкрипай - Do not as new questions in comments. Post a new question.